# error while verifying sql server database in coldfusion administrator

Tags: coldfusion

Connection verification failed for data source: HEMJOBS03
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:90. Reason: Connection refused: connect
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:90. Reason: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 3):

Looks like datasource configuration uses port 90 to connect, which is closed. See this chunk of your error `Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:90`.

So, obvious question: have you changed the connection port manually? If yes, are you sure it is correct port?